# Vuejs 'beforeunload' event not triggered as expected

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, dom-events, vue-router, addeventlistener

I have registered 'beforeunload' event on created hook of the component used by routes of vue router.

**I want to call this event handler in order to remove user on browser tab close or browser tab refresh or browser close.**

On ComponentA

```
created (){    
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {

        this.removeUser()

        return null
     })
}
```

Smilarly on ComponentB

```
created (){    
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {

        this.removeUser()

        return null
     })
}
```

And my router.js

```
{
  path: '/staff/call/:session_key',
  name: 'Staff Call',
  component: ComponentA,
  meta: {auth: true}
},
{
  path: '/consumer/call/:session_key',
  name: 'Consumer Call',
  component: ComponentB
},
```

Here 'beforeunload' event handler is triggered randomly. That is sometimes it get triggered and sometimes not. I count find any pattern when it is triggered and when it is not.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you seeing this randomness in a single browser?  Or different browser types/operating systems?  See [this browser compatibility page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FMozilla_event_reference%2Fbeforeunload) to see if you're having problems with a browser that doesn't support the event.

Answer (score 13):

***Edit*** 
I'd guess the most likely culprit then is exactly what @PatrickSteele said. From MDN:

> Note: To combat unwanted pop-ups, some browsers don't display prompts
>   created in beforeunload event handlers unless the page has been
>   interacted with; some don't display them at all. For a list of
>   specific browsers, see the Browser_compatibility section.

I'd say it's likely you're seeing inconsistent behavior because you are sometimes not interacting with the page.

This may be a syntax error. `created` should be a method

```
created () {    
        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.removeUser)  
    },

    methods: {
      removeUser () {
        //remove user here
      }
    }
```

A fiddle working: https://jsfiddle.net/e6m6t4kd/3/

Comment: Sorry my mistake.. I have edited the code. Still I am getting random behavior.

Comment: I'd say the most likely culprit then is exactly what @PatrickSteele said. From MDN:

```Note: To combat unwanted pop-ups, some browsers don't display prompts created in beforeunload event handlers unless the page has been interacted with; some don't display them at all. For a list of specific browsers, see the Browser_compatibility section.```

I'd say it's likely you're seeing inconsistent behavior because you are sometimes not interacting with the page.

Comment: I have tried everything but not thought about interaction with page. I will test and mark your answer correct. Please update ur answer.

Answer (score 5):

> **It's work for me. while do something before reload or close in
>   vue.js**

[image]

```
created() {
    window.onbeforeunload = function(){
           return "handle your events or msgs here";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had to do some fiddling on the above examples, I believe this is the most robust solution:

```
let app1 = new Vue({
    delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],       
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        dirty_form: true,
    },

    created () {
        console.log('created')
        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.confirm_leaving)
    },

    methods: {
        confirm_leaving (evt) {
            if (this.dirty_form) {
                const unsaved_changes_warning = "You have unsaved changes. Are you sure you wish to leave?";
                evt.returnValue = unsaved_changes_warning; 
                return unsaved_changes_warning;
            };
        };
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want detect page refresh/change in Vue whenever you press F5 or Ctrl + R, You may need to use [Navigation Timing API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation_timing_API).

The [PerformanceNavigation.type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigation/type), will tell you how the page was accessed.

```js
created() {
    // does the browser support the Navigation Timing API?
    if (window.performance) {
        console.info("window.performance is supported");
    }
    // do something based on the navigation type...
    if(performance.navigation.type === 1) {
        console.info("TYPE_RELOAD");
        this.removeUser();
    }
}
```

Comment: Great but this event handler can only be triggered on navigation. Cant use it for tab or browser close.  'beforeunload' event is triggered on both navigation and tab or browser close.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why none of the above were fully working for me in vue 3 composition api. Abdullah's answer partially works but he left out how to remove the listener.

```
setup() {

  const doSomething = (e) => {
    // do stuff here
    return true
  }

  onBeforeMount(() => {
    window.onbeforeunload = handleLeaveWithoutSaving
  })

  onUnmounted(() => {
    window.onbeforeunload = null
  })

}
```